# c# Data source can not be empty

Tags: c#, sqlite, input, textbox, datasource

The following code is used by me to load a set of items in sqlite database to a datagrid view upon a button click! When the path to the database is given as in the code the database is successfully connected and data is loaded.

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dbconnection = @" Data Source = D:\SQLite\SQLiteStudio\DB1.db ; version=3 ";
        }
```

but when i change the code as follows by obtaining the path as textbox input an error "Data source can not be empty" occurs. The name of the textbox used is dbtext and the same path in the above code is copied and pasted to the text box!

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dbconnection = @"Data Source="+dbtext.Text+";version=3";
        }
```

How can i correct this issue?

Comment: and what is the text of `dbtext.Text`

Comment: At what point is the path entered into the TextBox? After the program has already started? If so, the value is indeed never passed on to the connection string.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani the text box has the test D:\SQLite\SQLiteStudio\DB1.db

Comment: @waka after starting program only text is given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting it on form initialization where textbox is still empty and you set its value.

set `dbconnection = @"Data Source="+dbtext.Text+";version=3";` on Click event of the same button that loads the data or on textchanged event of the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the connection string in the constructor of your program:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dbconnection = @"Data Source="+dbtext.Text+";version=3";
}
```

At this point the `TextBox` is still empty and the variable `dbconnection` will look like this:

```
dbconnection = "DataSource=;version=3";
```

(check it in the debugger).

Now you are trying to establish a connection on your button click event, but to where? Instead, your code should look like this:

```
priavte void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dbconnection = "Data Source="+dbtext.Text+";version=3";
    //Do stuff with the connection
}
```